# What's the maximum supply voltage for a OPA2134PA?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, audio

I built a MOSFET driver using a TI 741 op-amp, sounds like garbage - because you know... its a 741.

I decided to continue my endeavors and purchase some better preamps and settled on a half-dozen TI Burr-brown OPA2134PA.

I *know* this is a basic question, but I would really appreciate the assistance:

What is the maximum supply voltage for this IC? I've got a dual DC 16v (36v total) supply. Will that cause issues?

I'm afraid I've fried all of them because they got EXTREMELY hot just by connecting the power pins. I even tried reducing current by connecting a 4.7k resistor between pin-7 and my positive supply - it still got super hot and produced no output! I'm at a loss!

**IC in question:**
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/OPA2134PA?qs=7nS3%252bbEUL6uyT34OzaiM4g%3D%3D

Comment: Read the datasheet. It says the supply should be between ±2.5V and ±18V. If by dual 16V you mean ±16V, then it should be fine; your power voltage isn't what's frying it.

Comment: Also, yes. I have consulted the data sheet. My understanding is that this IC gladly handles 38v.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that!! Man, I'm super bummed about this thing. (p.s. my comment above was typed before I saw your comment - it wasn't meant to be snarky as it may sound)

Comment: I would recommend double checking that your power supply is actually ±16V, and not misreporting its voltage, as well as checking that you don't have the IC the wrong way around (applying your power supply to the wrong pins can cause problems!), but anything I say is just speculation--I'm not sure what could be causing this really.

Comment: I'm a dumbass guys! Turns out I got the dual version of the 8 pin DIP and was using the datasheet for the single.

Much thanks for the sanity check!